# Subsonic and gridview control delete

Tags: asp.net, gridview, subsonic

Does anyone know how to use the gridview delete functionality with Subsonic 3?
I am trying to delete rows that do not have the primary key displayed in the the gridview so I can't just pull that data from the gridview row. I was wondering if there is a way to do it with the DataKeyNames property.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

This is what you do:

```
<asp:GridView ID="PageGrid" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="DeleteTheRow" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="centeredTableList" DataKeyNames="page_id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="page_name" HeaderText="Page Name" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="p={0}"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="page_id" HeaderText="Edit"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>



protected void DeleteTheRow(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(PageGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related or even applicable to a web-based Grid, but I usually use a BindingSource that I fill with my 'subsonicized' items like

```
bindingsource.DataSource = new ItemColleciton.Load();
```

Then when you need what is currently selected, I would get the Item with, for instance,

```
int pk = (bindingSource.Current as Item).PrimaryKey;
```

That way I think you get the actualy selected record, since maybe the RowIndex ina grid, may or may not be the correct one depending on the sorting or filtering?

Hope this helps.